# What technique they use to compress the URL's?

Tags: algorithm, compression

What algorithm/technique does most of the sites use to compress the URL?

Adfly shortens an URL e.g. to "5Y8F2" which is superb. It produces the most compressed URL I have ever seen.

Comment: "idm.6.09.2.final.sharepirate.com.rar"? Really?

Comment: @JonHanna:Could be worse.Could be a virus site...

Comment: @Cratylus maybe it is, but I'm not going to download that rar to find out.

Comment: They "compress" the URL by iterating over every possible URL of a given length, and matching the real URL to the shortened one in a database.

Answer (score 4):

You can find piece of information in Wiki: [URL shortening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening).

Quoting this article:

> There are several techniques to implement a URL shortening. Keys can be generated in base 36, assuming 26 letters and 10 numbers. In this case, each character in the sequence will be 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, a, b, c, ..., y, z. Alternatively, if uppercase and lowercase letters are differentiated, then each character can represent a single digit within a number of base 62 (26 + 26 + 10). In order to form the key, a hash function can be made, or a random number generated so that key sequence is not predictable. Or users may propose their own keys. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=TinyURL&diff=283621022&oldid=283308287 can be shortened to http://bit.ly/tinyurlwiki.

Answer (score 3):

I think they do not compress it they just generate a URL and map it to the real URL you compressed. So if they decide to make it N letters long they will be able to support (All Possible URL Characters)^N